# Pandas drop_duplicates method inconsistent result

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simple data frame. I'm trying to remove duplicate rows based on two columns.

```
import pandas as pd
b = pd.read_json('{"columns":["a","b"],"data":[[3110,75],[3110,75],[3115,75],[3120,75],[3123,75],[3129,75],[3134,75],[3137,75],[3129,75],[3110,29],[3115,29],[3120,29],[3123,29],[3129,29],[3134,29],[3137,29],[3129,29],[3110,62],[3115,62],[3120,62],[3123,62],[3129,62],[3134,62],[3137,62],[3129,62]]}', orient='split')
```

This yields a data frame that looks like:

```
    a       b
0   3110    75
1   3110    75  <-- duplicate
2   3115    75
3   3120    75
4   3123    75
5   3129    75
6   3134    75
7   3137    75
8   3129    75  <-- duplicate
9   3110    29
10  3115    29
11  3120    29
12  3123    29
13  3129    29
14  3134    29
15  3137    29
16  3129    29  <-- duplicate
17  3110    62
18  3115    62
19  3120    62
20  3123    62
21  3129    62
22  3134    62
23  3137    62
24  3129    62  <-- duplicate
```

If I just use `b.drop_duplicates()` I get (the incorrect):

```
b.drop_duplicates()['b'].value_counts()
29    7
75    7
62    6
Name: b, dtype: int64
```

But if I change the type to string using `b.astype(str).drop_duplicates()['b'].value_counts()` I get (the correct):

```
b.astype(str).drop_duplicates()['b'].value_counts()
62    7
75    7
29    7
Name: b, dtype: int64
```

Why is row 20 missing in the simplest application of drop_duplicates? Also why is the dtype int64 even after converting it to str as part of the process?

```
incorrect               correct
      a     b               a       b
0   3110    75          0   3110    75
2   3115    75          2   3115    75
3   3120    75          3   3120    75
4   3123    75          4   3123    75
5   3129    75          5   3129    75
6   3134    75          6   3134    75
7   3137    75          7   3137    75
9   3110    29          9   3110    29
10  3115    29          10  3115    29
11  3120    29          11  3120    29
12  3123    29          12  3123    29
13  3129    29          13  3129    29
14  3134    29          14  3134    29
15  3137    29          15  3137    29
17  3110    62          17  3110    62
18  3115    62          18  3115    62
19  3120    62          19  3120    62
21  3129    62          20  3123    62
22  3134    62          21  3129    62
23  3137    62          22  3134    62
                        23  3137    62

pd.__version__
'0.17.0'
```

The dtypes issue appears to be related to something happening automatically within the value_counts() method. Raw DataFrame output does reflect the conversion.

Comment: this is a bug in 0.17.0, fixed [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/11403) and will be in 0.17.1, releasing next week

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as the `drop_duplicates()`, what you're seeing is a known bug and should be fixed in `0.17.1` through merge [#11403](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/11403).

For the `astype`, `value_count()` will output a series with a dtype of `int64`. For permanent change you need to re-assign it, that means `b=b.astype('str')`

Comment: I was suspicious that this was a bug. Thanks for referencing the related github pull request. Regarding the reassignment, I disagree. I get same result if I do the conversion first and reassign or if I string it together. I'll accept the answer if you remove that part since it just causes confusion.

Comment: What I was referring to is that if you want to *permanently* change the type of `b` you have to reassign it, I'm assuming that was your question, correct? If you simply do `b.astype('str')` the type is only changed for whatever is being executed on that one line, in your case you're adding `.drop_duplicates()['b'].value_counts()` to it. Once that line is done executing, `b` will return to the type it was previously. Let me know if we're talking about the same thing.

Comment: Understood. I was asking about why the immediate result from value_counts didn't reflect the inline data type change. That seems to be related to something smart that value_counts does internally. See edit to original post.

Comment: Now I understand your second question, `values_counts` does output `int64` as the type. I included that in my edit.